# Nested objects in rails form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have following object structure to store some data.
ApplicationFrom has three attributes which are objects.
I am extending from ActiveModel for adding validations later.
details can be found here - [rails_casts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/219-active-model?autoplay=true)

```
module PipedriveApplicationForm
    class ApplicationForm
        include ActiveModel::Validations
        include ActiveModel::Conversion
        extend ActiveModel::Naming

        attr_accessor :org_details, :contact_details, :deal_details

        def initialize(attributes = {})
        attributes.each do |name, value|
            begin
                send("#{name}=", value)
            rescue => exception
            end
        end
      end
    end


    class OrgDetail
        include ActiveModel::Validations
        include ActiveModel::Conversion
        extend ActiveModel::Naming

        attr_accessor :businessDescription,
        :businessWebsite,

        def initialize(attributes = {})
        attributes.each do |name, value|
            begin
                send("#{name}=", value)   
            rescue => exception
            end
        end
      end
    end

    class ContactDetail
        include ActiveModel::Validations
        include ActiveModel::Conversion
        extend ActiveModel::Naming

        attr_accessor :ownerDOB

        def initialize(attributes = {})
        attributes.each do |name, value|
            begin
                send("#{name}=", value)   
            rescue => exception   
            end
        end
      end
    end

    class DealDetail
        include ActiveModel::Validations
        include ActiveModel::Conversion
        extend ActiveModel::Naming

        attr_accessor :purpose

        def initialize(attributes = {})
        attributes.each do |name, value|
            begin
                send("#{name}=", value)
            rescue => exception
            end
        end
      end
    end
end
```

In my controller I am construction folllowing object

```
def edit_application
      @application_details = PipedriveApplicationForm::DealDetail.new(application_detail)
      @person_details = PipedriveApplicationForm::ContactDetail.new(get_person_by_id(application_detail['data']['person_id']['value'])[:data])
      @org_details = PipedriveApplicationForm::OrgDetail.new(get_org_by_id(application_detail['data']['org_id']['value'])[:data])
      @pipedrive_application = PipedriveApplicationForm::ApplicationForm.new({org_details: @org_details, contact_details: @person_details, deal_details: @application_details})
end
```

Now in my form, I am doing this I am using fields_for to access the nested object and trying to update it.

```
    = form_for(@pipedrive_application, url: edit_application_path(current_user, @application), html: {method: :put})  do |f|
        = f.object.inspect
        = f.fields_for :deal_details do |ff|
            = ff.object.inspect
            %h4
                Application Details
            =ff.label :purpose
            =ff.text_field :purpose
```

The field values are not getting pre-populated . What's the problem here ?

Comment: There is a boatload of unessicarry duplication here that can be removed by using inheritance. Also you can use [ActiveModel::AttributeAssignment](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/AttributeAssignment.html) instead of duplicating the initialize method like this. `rescue => exception` is a also a huge antipattern as it will swallow any exception and make debugging extremely difficult.

Comment: thanks! for your suggestion